# Need to specify return type of a generic method that calls an API endpoint

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a generic method that does a Post:

```
protected async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string resource, object value = null)
{
    T result = default(T);

    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _baseUri + resource);

    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);

    if (value != null)
        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage))
    {
        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            //if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                //throw new HttpStatusCodeException((int)response.StatusCode, await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The API controller method that I am calling looks like this (I have omitted some implementation details). As you can see, it doesn't return any data:

```
[HttpPost("{contactId}/opt-out/test")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateTestAsync(Guid contactId, [FromQuery] string source)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Now using the generic Post method, I would like to know how to call the API endpoint. I have tried the following:

```
public async Task UpdateContactOptOutAsync(Guid contactId, string source)
{
    return await base.PostAsync<Task>($"contacts/{contactId}/opt-out/test?source={source}");
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Since 'BeamApiRepository.UpdateContactOptOutAsync(Guid, string)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?
```

So how do I specify a return type to call an API endpoint that doesn't return any value?

Answer (score 2):

it is better not to use it without T since it used to deserialize result. So I recomend to use it this way (PostAsync< Task > will work too)

```
public async Task UpdateContactOptOutAsync(Guid contactId, string source)
{
     await base.PostAsync<Task<object>>($"contacts/{contactId}/opt-out/test?source={source}");
}
```

if  your API dosn't return any data it will return null, otherwise it will  still return the result as an object instance. But the code ignores it since you have void method.  You can use var result = await base.Post.... and put some error code if it is not null, but it is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: so this method doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your Http client will likely not return a `Task<Task>` so why are you calling `PostAsync<Task>(...)`?

If you are using C# 7 or lower, you can simply call `PostAsync<object>(...)` which will always return null for the API you are calling.

If you are using C# 8 or higher, you can call `PostAsync<object?>(...)`.

Better yet, you can add a generic method which simply returns `Task` (with no return type), so it for API POST calls with no response body. That way, it is clear that the response has nothing.

```
protected async Task PostAsync(string resource, object value = null)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object> will probably fail. Unless maybe if the json contains $type

Comment: @Captain, I'm not suggesting what you are saying. I'm suggesting `PostAsync<object>(...)`. It seems works here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pczjLN

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the return `Task` type, like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateContactOptOutAsync(Guid contactId, string source)
{
    return await base.PostAsync<Task>($"contacts/{contactId}/opt-out/test?source={source}");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your own implementation of `Task` (and the generic type in the call to `PostAsync<Task>` is not a mistake) then you need `UpdateContactOptOutAsync` to return `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Task>`.

(just make sure to not mix-up the namespaces)

```
public async Task<Task> UpdateContactOptOutAsync(Guid contactId, string source)
```

Otherwise, if you haven't implemented your own `Task` class, then `UpdateContactOptOutAsync` should look something like this:

```
public async Task<MyResponse> UpdateContactOptOutAsync(Guid contactId, string source)
{
    return await base.PostAsync<MyResponse>($"contacts/{contactId}/opt-out/test?source={source}");
}
```

Where `MyResponse` is the actual type you expect to deserialize from the response.